# How can I detect whether scanned pages are empty using Python?

Tags: python, image

Let us suppose that there are pages (in the PNG format) obtained from paper sheets after scanning. Some of these sheets have neither text nor pictures; they look like a blank white paper sheet – an empty one. Is there a simple effective way to detect whether the pages are empty or not, using Python tools?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing examples of empty and non-empty pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this heuristic:

1. Binarize the image: if a Pixel is of a certain "darkness", make it black. Otherwise white.
2. Count the black pixels and divide by total pixels to get the black percentage
3. If the black percentage crosses a threshold, you can assume there is something. Try to find a good threshold (or use an absolute value instead of the black percentage )